# how to pivot a table in excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2010

I have my data in excel in the following presentation:

[image]
As you may see, in the first column I have the date and in the second column I have some values. However, I would like to have my data like this:

[image]

I would like to have my data grouped by month and year and shown in the image below. I've tried to use the pivot function but it seems not to be working. I would really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

before you can use a pivot table you need to add a few extra columns to your source data.  year and month, like this:

```
date        | close      | year             | month
01/01/2020    34,32       =TEXT(A2,"yyyy")    =TEXT(B2,"mmm")
```

then mark all the data in all 4 columns and go to insert -> pivottable.
in the pivottable field list add `month` to rows, `year` to columns and `close` to values

Comment: It seems not to be working. It works for month and year, but when I try to set ```close``` to values, in the table it appears a bunch of 1's.

Comment: make sure that `close` is not a text type in your original data, but a number. and make sure that the pivot table is set to `summarize values by sum` (right click menu on the piviot table) it sound like it is set to count